# What's the meaning of 帖子的顶楼？

Tags: word

I know 帖子 means post or thread on internet forum.

What is 顶楼? Is it the 1st reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all Internet slangs. Since a topic and all the replies look like a **building** (楼), each **reply** looks like a **floor** (楼层), the Chinese netizens call **to post a reply** as **to build a building** (盖楼), the person who starts the **thread**/**topic** is called **the host of the building** (楼主), and the first **reply** is called **the first floor** (一楼). 顶楼 (the topmost post) may be a variant name of 楼主 (or 一楼? I'm not sure), it's rarely seen. If 顶楼 is a phrase rather than a noun, its meaning likes 顶帖. Also, since the threads are sorted by the time of the last reply descendingly, 顶帖 can be be interpreted as 把帖子顶上去, which means to **raise up the thread**/**topic** (by posting a new reply intentionally).

Comment: And the person who reply a thread is called 层主

Comment: @sylvia You know that 层主 only exists in 百度贴吧, other forum system does not support leaving a simple comment to a reply.

Comment: Not necessarily. I know at least two other forum you can leave comment to replies..

Comment: @sylvia Actually, forum platforms like 百度贴吧 are rare until now, most forums may show comments under a reply but the comments themselves are also treated as normal replies and shown one more time in the replies list.

Comment: @sylvia I don't mean it's the unique one, I mean it's rarely seen. All that I know, it's the only one that show comments under a single reply only but not in replies list again.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it:

一楼 = first post

顶楼 = latest post

We often see post refer the previous posts as 楼下

Take [this page](https://www.comicbus.com/view/15828.html?ch=1) for example:

85樓 (2019-10-07 02:23) is the latest post

2樓  (2018-05-29 15:49) is the oldest post (一楼 must had been deleted)

Comment: latest post is not necessarily the 顶楼

Answer (score 1):

A post usually has a lot of replies or comments. 帖子的顶楼 means the reply(replies) or comment(s) at the top.